# Symfony2 "dummy parent" for collection field in a form, just for visualization

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

I have a Project entity which can have several Benefits.

Of course I have a Project form type to fill in all the info fields related to the project.

When I'm showing the Project X I need a link to "see benefits". There I'd have a list of benefits in a form, and I could add new ones or remove.

The relationship Project - Benefit is a one-to-many/many-to-one without join table.

To create the view of the form I thought about creating a "BenefitsFormType" (not the plural) that would simply be:

```
class BenefitsFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('benefits', 'collection', array('type' => new BenefitFormType(), 'allow_add'    => true, 'label' => false,
                        'by_reference' => false,
                        ))
                ->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Save'));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Benefits',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'Benefits';
    }
}
```

and the benefitFormType would have all the fields of each single Benefit.

The problem is that I don't need to store the Benefits class entity, the Benefits entity would simply be a collection of benefits for visualization purposes.

I don't know how to solve the issue without replicating the same relationship that I have between Projects and Benefit also between Benefits and Benefit.

I'm missing the easy way out for sure...

Comment: if you don't need to store a value, use 'mapped' => false option.

Comment: Yes, I know that option to avoid storing a field, but here we talk about the whole entity